# Can't submit app on iTunes connect: "New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store-connect

I get this error in iTunes connect when I tried to submit my app for review:

> New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions
>   of Xcode 6 or later, OS X, and iOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with
>   beta software including beta OS X builds.

I don't understand, I'm not using a beta version. I'm using Xcode 7.2. I updated my Mac two days ago and is now running OS X El Capitan 10.11.3.

Comment: Are you getting the error in Xcode during upload, or actually in iTunes Connect after upload? If the former, that sometimes happens for unknown reasons (and resolves itself after a few hours/days). Using Application Loader instead of Xcode to upload the binary is usually an effective workaround.

Comment: I get the error in iTunes connect.

Comment: So the upload is successful in Xcode, but you have the error in iTunes Connect? Haven't seen that one before, but you may try the Application Loader route anyway.

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that the problem is related to MacOS update 10.11.3. Maybe the engineers at Apple have not yet updated the backend on which runs iTunesConnect in order to reflect the new OSX Version.

[Here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31066) others developers are complaining about.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the recent MacOS update to 10.11.3.
It's just a matter of waiting until Apple updates iTunes Connect to recognize it as a valid OS version.

Comment: I have the same issue too, let's wait a couple of hours